# fnFilter is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to search in a DataTables column for values selected in a multi select box. I read the values selected in the multi select box to a variable and joined them with "|". I then tried to use the fnFilter for the search, and my code goes as follows: 
This is how I initiated the table:

```
var table = jQuery(tableId).DataTable(settings);
```

where settings are the datatables global settings. Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery('#box2').change(function() {
                var foo = [];
                jQuery('#box2 :selected').each(function(j, selected){
                  foo[j] = jQuery(selected).text();               
                });
                var m= foo.join("|");
                table.fnFilter(m, 2, true, false, true, true);
});
```

This returns the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: table.fnFilter is not a function
```

Is it anything wrong with my code? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The posted code looks okay to me. Can you make a working snippet?

Comment: Two things to check.  Did you really call `DataTable` and not `dataTable`?  If you did the latter, you'll get that error.  Did you set `filter` or `bFilter` to false in your settings?

Comment: @BobRodes I did call it DataTable and I did not include any of those in my settings. Is there any other way to do what I intended to? Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for the reply. Is there any other way to do what I intended to?

Comment: @BobRodes, it is the opposit, if you initialize with `DataTable()` the old jQuery object function `fnFilter()` is unavailable.  However, `jQuery(tableId).dataTable().fnFilter(m, 2, true, false, true, true)` will work, even if the table is already initialized with `DataTable()` you just get the jQuery object in return.

Comment: @davidkonrad if I try making it table.dataTable().fnFilter(m, 2, true, false, true, true), it is returning an error saying table.dataTable is not a function

Comment: @rav,  try read my comment again.

Comment: @davidkonrad Hmm.  I'm just going by the doc, which says this: "It is important to note the difference between $( selector ).DataTable() and $( selector ).dataTable(). The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object. An api() method is added to the jQuery object so you can easily access the API, but the jQuery object can be useful for manipulating the table node, as you would with any other jQuery instance (such as using addClass(), etc.)." Doesn't that mean that you don't have access to the API if you use `dataTable`, and doesn't `fnFilter` need the API?

Comment: I mean, don't you have to use either `DataTable().fnFilter` or `dataTable.api().fnFilter()`?  That's what I'm reading from the doc.

Comment: @BobRodes, yes, the documentation is right, but it was not the docs I commented but that you wrote "_Did you really call DataTable and not dataTable? If you did the latter, you'll get that error_" and it is not "the latter" but the first method `DataTable()` that will cause that error.

Comment: I guess that's what I don't understand.  I'm reading the doc to say if you call `dataTable.fnFilter()` you'll get the error, since `dataTable` on its own doesn't have a reference to the API.

Comment: @davidkonrad Ok, I've been doing some testing, and it is of course as you say.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I got confused by the doc.

Answer (score 13):

datatables 1.10 having different api.

```
$().DataTable
```

is different with

```
$().datatable
```

change your api like this :

```
table.search(your_key).draw();
```

Answer (score 6):

In older versions of DataTable, you have to use `fnFilter` and for DataTable version 1.10 you must use `search`.

As I can see your code you're using `jQuery(tableId).DataTable(settings);` (version 1.10)

So, the solution would be:

```
var table = jQuery(tableId).DataTable(settings);
table.search(value).draw();
```

But, in older DataTable versions the table initiated by small **d** something like this `jQuery(tableId).dataTable();`. So, in this case you can use `fnFilter`

```
var table = jQuery(tableId).dataTable();
table.fnFilter(value);
```

To read more about [DataTable -
 fnFilter](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter) and [DataTable -
 search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. The following worked for me:

```
var dataTable = $('#myTableId').dataTable();
```

**NOT**

```
var dataTable = $('#myTableId').DataTable();
```

Change *DataTable* to *dataTable*

Comment: LOL this would have been fun to be looking for. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and the following solution did worked for me.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // if you initialize with DataTable() the old jQuery object function fnFilter() is unavailabl
        // var table = $('#populateTable').DataTable({ 

        var table = $('#populateTable').dataTable({
            searching: true,
            info: true,
            lengthChange: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "product/getProductDataset",
            dataSrc: 'data',
            columns: [
                { data: 'product_title' },
                { data: 'product_category' },
                { data: 'product_brand' },
                { data: 'price_crawled_date' },
                { data: 'product_lowest_price', orderable: false },
                { data: 'actions', orderable: false }
            ]
        }); // End: DataTable

        $('div.dataTables_filter input').unbind();
        $('div.dataTables_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                table.fnFilter(this.value);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Happy coding :)**